# How to find version of Drupal installed

Tags: drupal

How can I know which version of Drupal is installed in my server?

Comment: Most of these answers are pretty dated, I had to use the answer to check in Drupal.php for /VERSION/. It's got a peasy 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 60):

You can get this by logging in to admin. Go to Administer → Reports → Status Report.

This will let you know all your config information of the site including your Drupal version.

Comment: URL will be `/admin/reports/status`

Comment: This only give you the first part. I often see modules that requires for example 7.x-1.5. So here you will get the 7.x. but where to get the "-1.5" part?

Comment: @GuillaumeBois, Drupal versioning is only two-numbered. Versioning like "7.x-1.5" used only for modules express that some version is compatibile with eg. Drupal 7.x, and "-1.5" part is in deed version of the module.

Answer (score 38):

You can also type:

`drush status` in your project folder. It will print out something like this:

```
$ drush status
 Drupal version         :  7.27 **<--**
 Default theme          :  garland
 Administration theme   :  garland
 PHP executable         :  php
 PHP configuration      :  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\Php\php.ini"
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush version          :  6.0
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :  c:/users/spaden/.drush/pantheon.aliases.drushrc.php
 Drupal root            :  c:/Users/spaden/localSite/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have drush installed... http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Note that for me the project folder was `/opt/bitnami/drupal` found using `sudo find / -type d -name drupal`

Answer (score 35):

To easily check Drupal version, go to `www.yourwebsite.com/CHANGELOG.txt`

`CHANGELOG.txt` will show you the version and change log updates to the Drupal build version.

Comment: A lot of people recommend removing that file, so it will not be available everywhere.

Comment: Most of the site owners remove CHANGELOG.txt so as to keep their site information hidden from intruders.

Comment: @jaesperanza this boggles my mind... If I manually update drupal (delete files on site, copy new drupal version up and run update.php) and it fails... the changelog is going to say "new version" even tho it didn't successfully update. btw, i've used other CMS's, the whole delete files upload files process seems real stupid to me.

Comment: @nthChild you should not delete the `sites` folder. Delete everything except for `sites` folder. Or you can actually just copy paste as it will update all the corresponding files. Be sure to backup some of the files like `robots.txt` if you modified it before updating the core. After updating the core the next thing that you need to do is to run `drush updb` or `/update.php`.

Answer (score 23):

This is defined as a global PHP variable in `/includes/bootstrap.inc` within D7. Example: `define('VERSION', '7.14');` So use it like this...

```
if (VERSION >= 7.1) {
  do_something();
}
```

Comment: this is the source for `drush status` in case you can't use that

Comment: **Drush is an optional command line utility.** Anyone asking this question has likely inherited a system and does not have command line tools installed on the production server they find themselves managing ;)

Comment: exactly. having fallen into a broken environment where drush was missing, this answer led me to the place in bootstrap where drush itself finds the version. thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh, glad you found the innards.

Comment: @doublejosh or, like me, they don't know which particular Drush spell to invoke.

Answer (score 20):

***In Drupal 7***

Open CHANGELOG.txt and the top most version will be the installed version.

***In Drupal 8***

Open core/lib/Drupal.php file and there will be a version mentioned like 
const VERSION = '8.1.8';

***Drush Tool***

Drush status

***Admin Interface***

Go to Administer -> Reports -> Status Report or enter URL /admin/reports/status

> Above is the simplest way otherwise installed ***wappalyzer*** browser
>   addons and see the magic.

Comment: Solution for Drupal 8 works also in Drupal 9 :-)

Answer (score 11):

Log into Drupal admin interface. Then go to "Administer -> Available Updates". And you'll be able to see what drupal version your are using.

or you can go to the file /modules/system/system.info and you will see something like
version = "6.2"

Answer (score 6):

**From the database**

Run the following query:

```
SELECT info FROM system WHERE type = 'module' AND name = 'node';
```

After, you will receive a serialized string value like:

> a:10:{s:4:"name";s:4:"Node";s:11:"description";s:66:"Allows content to be submitted to the site and displayed on pages.";s:7:"package";s:15:"Core - required";s:7:"version";s:4:"6.20";s:4:"core";s:3:"6.x";s:7:"project";s:6:"drupal";s:9:"datestamp";s:10:"1292447788";s:12:"dependencies";a:0:{}s:10:"dependents";a:0:{}s:3:"php";s:5:"4.3.5";}

Then, unserialize this string. You can use the [php unserialize function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) or any online web service such as: http://unserialize.me

You should see two array elements as below which shows the current version number:

```
[version] => 6.20
[core] => 6.x
```

Comment: I tried this and got a string like `\x613a31353a7...` instead. Any idea what encoding that can be?

Comment: And if the `system` table doesn't exist, you might be running Drupal 8 or higher.

Answer (score 5):

**The really easy way is:** go to your site, and into the Browser go to: view source.

Generally you can find:

```html
<meta name="generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
```

Or just press: Ctrl/Cmd "F": And find the word Drupal.

You will find the Drupal version in the code without check anything in the admin.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 8 programmatically: `\DRUPAL::VERSION`

Answer (score 4):

**For Drupal7**

Two ways you can find installed drupal version.for this you have to logged in as  admin.

1.Go to Url 'admin/reports/status',on status report page it will show first drupal with its version.

2.Go to Url 'admin/modules',on finding core tab ,we can find drupal contributed modules with 'version'.

**For Drupal8**

Open drupal\core\lib\Drupal.php in your text editor

you will see something like this (from line 79 to line 84)

```html
open drupal\core\lib\Drupal.php in your text editor

you will see something like this (from line 79 to line 84)

class Drupal {

/**
* The current system version.
*/
const VERSION = '8.2.3';
```

Answer (score 2):

For older versions you can find the details here:
modules/system/system.module

One of my installs says:

define('VERSION', '5.6');

Answer (score 2):

use drush to know which drupal version you are using.
command : drush status

Below is the list of information it will show:

```
Drupal version : 8.7.10                                                  
 Site URI       : http://default                                          
 DB driver      : mysql                                                   
 DB hostname    : localhost                                               
 DB port        : 3306                                                    
 DB username    : root                                                    
 DB name        : drupal_8_7_10                                           
 PHP binary     : /usr/bin/php7.4                                         
 PHP config     : /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini                                
 PHP OS         : Linux                                                   
 Drush script   : /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-8.7.10/vendor/drush/drush/drus 
                  h                                                       
 Drush version  : 10.2.0                                                  
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                                    
 Drush configs  : /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-8.7.10/vendor/drush/drush/drus 
                  h.yml                                                   
 Drupal root    : /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-8.7.10                         
 Site path      : sites/default
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, looking at any .info file on your Drupal instance in any theme or module folder (inside /sites/all) may be easiest/quickest for you as opposed to adding PHP code though both are quite easy.

If for any reason you don't have FTP/SSH access to your Drupal server, there are other ways like viewing page source in the browser (if you know what look for) or a simple browser pluggin such as 'Drupal for Firebug' or similar utlity:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/drupal-for-firebug/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can install Drupal version check plugin in your browser and click on the drupal icon in your navigation bar. This is the easiest way to check Drupal version.

Here is the link to the plugin - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/drupal-version-check/

Comment: "This add-on has been removed by its author."

Answer (score 1):

Open project folder.
Look for CHANGELOG.txt and open it.
Here you can find version.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 
admin->modules->(see version of core module like block )
admin->reports->status->drupal version

Drupal 8 
admin->reports->updates : see Drupal core

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve by following ways:

By Composer: simply type  "*drush status*" It will give you all
information about Drupal version, theme, modules version along with
PHP versioning.

By Front End: hit https://WEBSITE_NAME/changelog.txt It will give you
version information on browser. If if is your site it is recommended
to remove this file.

By Back End: Login to your backend as admin and go to status under
reports from admin toolbar or hit
https://WEBSITE_NAME/admin/reports/status

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal admin panel, you can find using the menu as follows,
Drupal admin **Reports->Status report**.
 or else

You can find Drupal version via URL or View Source.

URL=> type **CHANGELOG.txt** in http://example.com/CHANGELOG.txt

View Source => You can find this by the following [meta tag]

[image]

This meta tag appears only in Drupal Site. You can confirm that the web application is based on Drupal CMS.

Comment: it is a good practice (security wise) to remove the CHANGELOG, just FYI in case you don't find that file in some of your projects

Answer (score -1):

To find the version of Drupal installed, follow these steps:

- Log in to your Drupal website as an administrator.
- Go to the "Reports" section in the admin panel, located under the
  "Reports" tab.
- Scroll down to the "System Information" section, and look for the
  "Drupal Version" field.
- The version of Drupal installed will be displayed next to "Drupal
  Version."

**Note:** If you do not have access to the Drupal admin panel, you can also check the version of Drupal installed by looking at the version number in the "core" directory located in the Drupal installation directory. Drupal 8,9 /web/core/lib/Drupal.php