# What version of drupal is installed?

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal installation but no functioning website.  How do I find what version of Drupal is installed through the command line?

I cannot login to the site, so the answers here:
[How to find version of Drupal installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887282/how-to-find-version-of-drupal-installed) do not help.  I am limited to using the command line with access to the file system.

Comment: Do you have Drush installed? If so, use `drush status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Drush installed, you can use `drush status` and it will print out the Drush version and the Drupal version you have installed.

If not, go into your Drupal root directory and take a look at the `CHANGELOG.txt` file. It will list the most recent upgrade (the current version) at the top.

**Edit**

If you do not have the `CHANGELOG.txt` file, and don't have Drush, you can look in the `includes/bootstrap.inc` file, as suggested in the third answer to the question you linked to.

> This is defined as a global PHP variable in /includes/bootstrap.inc within D7. Example: define('VERSION', '7.14'); So use it like this...
>
> `if (VERSION >= 7.1) {
>    do_something();
>   }`

Comment: Thank you for answering!  Unfortunately, I do not have Drush installed, and `CHANGELOG.txt` has been removed.  Both of these were suggested in the thread I linked to.  I was hoping for a simpler answer, I suppose.

Comment: @JonahHuron I changed my answer to add another way to find it. :)

Comment: That ought to work.  We've shut down the machine now, so I can't try it, but as I recall, I couldn't find that file.  `find` seemed to hang every time I tried it, and it wasn't in any obvious place (obvious to me, at least).  I'll mark this as "answered," but if you could suggest a default absolute path to `bootstrap.inc`, it would probably help others in my situation.  Thanks again!

Comment: The path I gave was relative to the Drupal root. Unfortunately I cannot suggest an absolute path relative to the machine because everyone's setup is different, but the path is "absolute" from the Drupal root.