# Password reset but Dupal doesn't have pass field in the users table?

Tags: authentication, drupal, change-password

I'm trying to [reset the admin password for a Drupal account](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428), but it doesn't seem to have a `pass` field in the `users` table.

```
UPDATE users
SET pass ='$S$CTo9G7Lx28rzCfpn4WB2hUlknDKv6QTqHaf82WLbhPT2K5TzKzML'
WHERE uid = 1;
```

Instead it has a `pass` field in the table `users_field_data`. What does this mean about Drupal?

I can't find any docs on the `users_field_data` table.

I'm on Drupal VERSION = '8.2.7';

```
mysql> show create table users;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `langcode` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_field__uuid__value` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='The base table for user entities.' |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You're on Drupal 8

There are different tables and schema for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Those instructions are for Drupal 7. If there is no `pass` in the `users` table and you have a `users_field_data` [you need to find the *other* instructions for Drupal 8.](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/07/resetting-the-administrator-password-with-sql-query-in-drupal-8/)

Hint it's pretty simple

1. You're changing the table name, `users_field_data` is in fact the right table.

   ```
   UPDATE users_field_data
   SET pass= hash_generated_with_password-hash.sh
   WHERE uid = 1;
   ```
2. In addition you have to delete the cache

   ```
   DELETE FROM cache_entity
   WHERE cid = 'values:user:1';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7's [schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.install/function/user_schema/7.x) definitely has a `pass` field in the `users` table.

You may want to use backticks around the `pass` field:

```
UPDATE users
SET `pass` ='$S$CTo9G7Lx28rzCfpn4WB2hUlknDKv6QTqHaf82WLbhPT2K5TzKzML'
WHERE uid = 1;
```

If that doesn't work, and a close inspection of the table in a MySQL client doesn't show a field, I'd worry about someone having inadvertently deleted it. This database structure is seen in Drupal 8, though, so check your version closely.

Comment: see my update? I dumped it and no pass. It's in the `users_field_data` table. This isn't a fresh install it's a production product and I want to know what this means for the product or what customization happened

Comment: Drupal 8 appears to use the `users_field_data` model, so something very screwy is going on if your admin says you're on Drupal 7.

Comment: I just saw that because it's in the CHANGELOG perhaps I'm on Drupal 8. What's the best way to find out what version of Drupal I'm on?

Comment: @EvanCarroll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887282/how-to-find-version-of-drupal-installed

Comment: I see it I'm on   const VERSION = '8.2.7';

Comment: OK, then you're on Drupal 8. The answer to your question "What does this mean about Drupal?" thus is "absolutely nothing". Use a Drupal 8 tutorial for resetting your password.

Comment: The answers not "absolutely nothing" but thanks for rejecting my previous guess that it was Drupal 7. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the password using drush

```
drush upwd USERNAME PASSWORD
```